# Does Medusa's Wrath activate during the full-attack action in which you inflict a qualifying condition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats

[Medusa's Wrath](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/medusa-s-wrath-combat-final/):

> Whenever you use the full-attack action and make at least one unarmed strike, you can make two additional unarmed strikes at your highest base attack bonus. These bonus attacks must be made against a dazed, flat-footed, paralyzed, staggered, stunned, or unconscious foe.

If I cause at least one of the listed conditions (via [Stunning Fist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stunning-fist-combat-final/), possibly disarming an opponent while using a one-handed improvised weapon with the [Catch Off Guard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/catch-off-guard-combat/) feat, etc) during a full attack action, can I use the 2 extra strikes from the Medusa's Wrath feat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can use the attacks because the ability does not specify that you must initiate your attack on such a target.**

The Feat requires:

- You make at least one Unarmed Strike during your Full Attack
- The enemy(ies) you target with the feat are under one of the conditional requirements requirements

The Unarmed Strike is the trigger for the feat, the conditions are a restriction about who you can target with the additional strikes.

Answer (score 2):

Catch Off Guard does not qualify as Medusa's Wrath qualifying condition since it applies a flat-footed condition **only against any attacks you make with an improvised melee weapon**, not every attack.

In short, you are not flat-footed for the whole round and succeeding attacks, only for that single improvised melee weapon attack.

Comment: I think this 'answer' would be better off as a comment "you should edit this section out" when you get higher reputation or a self-answer Question