# Does staggered also mean hindered?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monk, conditions

#### Does staggered constitute as hindered for triggering to the Medusa's Wrath feat?

So I am playing a pathfinder game with some buds, and I made a monk (Core, not unchained). Under scorpion style there are two other moves that I could get later. Gorgon's fist makes the creature staggered, and then Medusa's wrath gives me 2 extra attacks on a hindered enemy.  It is unclear what hindered means.  The book doesn't have this answer as hindered isn't a condition listed.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: It's worth noting that Scorpion Style/Gorgon Fist/Medusa's Wrath *are not* a Style feat tree as per [Style Feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/style-feats). You don't need to 'enter' Scorpion Style, and you do not need to use (or even have) Scorpion Style/Gorgon Fist to benefit from Medusa's Wrath. (You can get Medusa's Wrath without otherwise qualifying for it with Monk Bonus Feats)

Answer (score 9):

You're correct that hindered isn't among the game's [conditions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/), but, fortunately, the current version of the feat [Medusa's Wrath](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/medusa-s-wrath-combat-final/) has as its benefit the following:

> Whenever you use the full-attack action and make at least one unarmed strike, you can make two additional unarmed strikes at your highest base attack bonus. These bonus attacks must be made against a dazed, flat-footed, paralyzed, staggered, stunned, or unconscious foe.

…So the current benefit doesn't mention hindered at all! (It's possible to infer from the feat [Gorgon's Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/gorgon-s-fist-combat-final/) that *hindered* could mean that the creature's speed is reduced such as with the result of the feat [Scorpion Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/scorpion-style-combat-final/), but I'm speculating here.)

Anyway, this means that if, on one turn, your monk staggers a foe using the feat [Gorgon's Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/gorgon-s-fist-combat-final/) then, on your monk's next turn, your monk can totally open a can of Medusa's Wrath on that staggered foe.

Comment: Thank you so much. The wording from the version I am using confused the hell out of me. I am glad that the newer version clarifies. :)

Comment: @Drizna You're welcome, and it was my pleasure. Because I'm curious: What printing of the book are you using? And is it in a language other than English?

Comment: I just checked, and I'm using a pdf file, but it is the Beta test version. I missed that part. :( I feel foolish now. Do you have a link to a pdf of the most up to date version?

Comment: @Drizna The site forbids piracy, but everything you need—and, probably, far, *far* more than you want—is made available for free and in a completely legal way on [d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/).

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I try not to pirate the books either, I usually just go to the first site that I see. I want a legal way to get the information as well. :) Thanks again.

Comment: [Medusa's Wrath can be used on the same turn a valid target is given one of the listed conditions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96963/does-medusas-wrath-activate-during-the-full-attack-action-in-which-you-inflict)

Comment: @Ifusaso This answer doesn't deny that? However, a creature *really* must take a standard action use the benefit of the feat Gorgon's Fist, making it so that, if the creature uses the feat Gorgon's Fist to apply the condition to a foe, it's usually impossible for the typical creature *on the same turn* to realize the benefit of the feat Medusa' s Wrath against that *same* foe.